# I have radio button for the user to choose if he/she wants to keep his/her account logged in.

Tags: android

How do I assign SharedPreferences on the radiobutton? Please I really need help.

Answer (score 1):

This should work ...

```
SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("preferencesName", MODE_PRIVATE);
final SharedPreferences.Editor prefEdit = pref.edit();

RadioButton radio = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio);
radio.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        prefEdit.putBoolean("booleanValue", isChecked).commit();
    }
});
```

Comment: Where shout I put this? in the oncreate? Actually, I have two radio buttons, the yes or no buttons, if yes then sharedpreferences will save the user's credentials and will keep her account logged in, if no then nothing happens

Comment: You should put this in onCreate or onResume, and you should probably modify it to suit your needs. Why do you use two RadioButtons? Use ToggleButton in stead.

Comment: Can you detail me this Sharedpreferences method? I'm still a beginner here in android, and i wanna learn this sharedpreferences method.

Comment: You should probably read the official documentation - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html and ask specific questions (if you have them) afterwards.

Comment: Thank you, it works now. One more thing, what if the user chose the off button i want the activity to return to login page when the user comes back again

Comment: depends ... you could call finish() on this activity and launch a startActivity() for the login? I don't know how your project is constructed :)

Comment: @LambergaR: What if I have a list of radio buttons? Will the above method work? How will I know which radio button is selected when I load the list again?

Comment: you could just save the index of the selected RadioButton and select the appropriate one on onResume

Answer (score 0):

the above code is for putting the value of radio button through shared preferences and for reading value of radio button whether it is checked or not , use the following code

```
SharedPreferences prefs = activity.getSharedPreferences("preferencesName", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
Boolean value= prefs.getBoolean(booleanValue, false);
```